# 3 OR Conditions in Bash Statement

Tags: bash, scripting

I would think this would be simple, but I keep getting errors. I want 3 OR conditions in my if else statement. These are the variations I've tried. What syntax error am I making?

```
   if [[ $var == "a" ]] || [[ $var == "b" ]] || [[ $var == "c" ]]; then
#Do Stuff
    else
#Do Stuff
    fi

    if [ $var == "a" ] || [ $var == "b" ] || [ $var == "c" ]; then
#Do Stuff
    else
#Do Stuff
    fi

    if [[ $var == "a" ] || [ $var == "b" ]] || [ $var == "c" ]; then
#Do Stuff
    else
#Do Stuff
    fi

    if [[ $var == "a"  || $var == "b" || $var == "c" ]]; then
#Do Stuff
    else
#Do Stuff
    fi
```

Comment: First `if` should work with `bash`.

Comment: Okay awesome! I was getting a flag error that I thought was related to this if statement, but it might be something else. Thanks!

Comment: Please  add complete error message to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and last versions both look and act correctly for me. Are you sure you are using `bash` and not `sh`?

Note that `[` and `[[` are both "commands" (built-ins really, I think is the appropriate term) and are slightly different. Basically you want to use `[[` unless you want legacy compatibility with old shells. If using `[` there are additional considerations, for example it can cause problems with empty string comparisons.

Also as an aside, the 2nd version should generally work, but you get the problems mentioned above - and the 3rd version is not good.

Comment: The second version *might* work; to make it work consistently in any POSIX shell, add double-quotes around the variable references, and use `=` instead of `==`. That is, `if [ "$var" = "a" ] || ...`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't quite sure about the details.